# Why won't this RAM work in my HP Proliant DL380 G4 server?

Tags: hp, memory, hp-proliant, ecc

I tried installing some Crucial 1024MB PC5400 DDR2 667MHz ECC Memory (CT12872AA667) and the system would not start - just post beeps.

The original memory is PC2-3200R ECC and the place I purchased the new RAM from does not have anything that low in speed. I figured the 5400 should be fine as usually they run at the lower speed.

Can I do something to make it work, or am I out of luck?

Searching online I have found a couple sites that are selling 5400 speed RAM specifically for it!

Comment: I know this is a newb type question, but why the vote downs?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but: Hover over the vote down button and it tells you 'This question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful'. With respect, I'd suggest that the first part of that statement could be used to describe this question. For a start, you mention crucial and their website offers a tool that tells you precisely what type of memory is needed for damn near all computers that major vendors like HP have produced.

Comment: I understand, but that's the one thing about these sites I don't like -rather than a down vote, why not a meaningful, educational answer such as the one you just provided.  I found the (incorrect) ram by searching google.  From now on I might start with the crucial site.

Comment: (not trying to be snarky or pedantic, and apologies for chiming in years later, Q was just flagged for mod attention) People downvote and don't answer because it takes more effort to come up with a correct answer, and most people are reluctant to put that effort into a question that shows a distinct lack of effort. GIGO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've bought unbuffered memory, not registered memory, that model won't run with unbuffered memory.

You should have bought Crucial P/N: CT820201.

Sorry.